# virt-manager MX Linux host, Android x86 guest share folder

Tags: linux, android, shared-folders, virt-manager

How can I share folder between Linux host and Android guest? Tried to add USB and file system hw, but couldn't make them work, I could share folder and copy/paste with Windows guest, what I'm missing?